# PHP & Perl behavior when testing "0", "-0", "0.0", "00",

Tags: php, string, perl, comparison, semantics

I came across this interesting behavior when PHP/Perl tests a value

```
print "0"   ? "Yes" : "No"; // => No
print "00"  ? "Yes" : "No"; // => Yes
print "0.0" ? "Yes" : "No"; // => Yes
print "-0"  ? "Yes" : "No"; // => Yes
print "+0"  ? "Yes" : "No"; // => Yes
print "0 "  ? "Yes" : "No"; // => Yes
```

So it seems the numeric value within the string doesn't really matter, but there is a specific case for the string `"0"`.

What surprised me the most is that Perl does behave the same.
Why is there a specific case for the string being exactly `"0"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the ternary operator which checks for the *truthiness* of the expression before the `?`. The *truthiness* of values is described in the [***Booleans***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) section:

> When converting to bool, the following values are considered `false`:
>
> - the boolean `false` itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from attributeless empty elements, i.e. elements which have neither children nor attributes.
>
> Every other value is considered true (including any resource and NAN).

So yes, the string `"0"` is treated as a special case.

---

Perl's [Truth and Falsehood](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Scalar-values) behave like somewhat like PHP.

Comment: As the question is also flagged `perl` you may wish to add http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood to your answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Note that in Python*, `"0"` is *True*

Answer (score 3):

It's just because of typecasting in PHP. You have an empty string only in two cases: "" and "0"

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: This is not "just" typecasting: "00" evaluates to true, "0" evaluates to false ("0.0", "+0" ... evaluate to true as well). There is a specific case of the very string "0".

Comment: The rule about converting string to boolean is simple. String is false: 
the empty string, and the string "0" 

It may seem strange? Maybe. And not only in this case.