# PHP check if a variable is empty or not

Tags: php, if-statement

In my case, the variables `$nr` and `$str` can have only two possible values. $nr can contain integer/numeric or null, not "null" between double quotes. $str can contain a string value or null. Can I just check if the variables are empty or not like this?

```
if ($nr) {}
if (! $nr) { return; }
if ($str) {}
if (! $str) { return; }
```

I think the answer is Yes but some code snippets of others made me doubt about that because they check it as following.

```
if (empty($var) || "" === $var || null === $var) { return; }}
```

I think this is unnecessary. To be specific, it is in PHP7.4.

Comment: either they specifically means something with this conditions or they are completely noob.

Comment: you can read on php.net about what values are checked by `empty`, that should be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Can you share sample data that is not covered by the given check?

Comment: It's not clear what you really want to achieve with this condition. You say "empty", but I'm not sure you really mean empty. `0` is considered empty and falsey, as well as an empty string. Do you want to detect those or only the `null` values?

Comment: This, however, is completely redundant: `if (empty($var) || "" === $var || null === $var)` because `empty` already covers those cases.

Comment: `null` is caught simply with `!$var`. `0` and `"0"` would also be caught by it though. If your legitimate expected values ***cannot*** be `0` or `""` or `"0"`, then just `if ($var)`/`if (!$var)` will do just fine. Don't use `empty` needlessly, since its only job is to suppress errors for non-existent variables in a `!$var` test; you don't want to suppress errors unless you have to.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried `$nr = null`, `$nr = ""`, `$nr = 0`, `$nr = false` and `if ($nr) { ... }` works correctly. I am not stuck anywhere, I just want to ask if my $nr will contain only integer/numeric or null, is it correct to just use `if($nr){ ... }` or it is not enough and I have use the long if-statement as showing above.

Comment: Why not write a test case covering the different input and output combinations?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have read my question again. It seems to be really clear. My `$str` can be `null` or `some words`. Is it correct to just use if($str){ // do something } or it is not enough and I have use the long if-statement as showing above.

Comment: Well, that really depends on the logic of your application. That's what I felt was unclear. @deceze covered it pretty well in his comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can check https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php to see what can be used to check if something is truthy or falsy. Below is the table of the link before condensed into a table of things you can plug into an if statement and what the results will be.

> Before utilizing these tables, it's important to understand types and their meanings. For example, `"42"` is a string while `42` is an int. `false` is a bool while `"false"` is a string.

| Expression | bool : if($x) |
| --- | --- |
| $x = ""; | false |
| $x = null; | false |
| var $x; | false |
| $x is undefined | false |
| $x = array(); | false |
| $x = array('a', 'b'); | true |
| $x = false; | false |
| $x = true; | true |
| $x = 1; | true |
| $x = 42; | true |
| $x = 0; | false |
| $x = -1; | true |
| $x = "1"; | true |
| $x = "0"; | false |
| $x = "-1"; | true |
| $x = "php"; | true |
| $x = "true"; | true |
| $x = "false"; | true |

Comment: Reminds me of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646843/php-perl-behavior-when-testing-0-0-0-0-00), regarding the special case of `"0"`...

Comment: yup, automatic typecasting can trip you up. There are so many edge cases, I tend to just work with them but not conciously thinking about them. after 15 years you kinda just roll with it

Answer (score 1):

`if ($var)`/`if (!$var)` simply check for *truthy/falsey* values respectively (they're complimentary opposites, which one you choose is merely a question of which makes more sense in your flow). [Falsey values in PHP are](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

- `false`
- `null`
- `0`, `-0`, `0.0`, `-0.0`
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `""` (empty string)
- `array()` (empty array)
- empty `SimpleXML` objects <sub>(interesting special case; thanks Obama! )</sub>

**Everything else is truthy.**

So, if none of your *desired* values fall into this list and all of your *undesired* values are in this list, then a simple `if ($var)`/`if (!$var)` will do just fine. If your desired/undesired list does not happen to align with this and you want some of column A but also some of column B, then you need to do more specific and complicated checks.

The only time you'll want to use `emtpy` is if the variable you're checking may legitimately **not exist.** `empty($var)` is just `!$var`, but doesn't raise an error if `$var` doesn't exist at all. That's its only purpose, and you do not want to suppress error reporting unless you have to. In a properly written program where you declare your variables properly, there should be very *very* little use for `empty`, since you should know what variables exist and which don't.